# VS 2012 find and replace text outside string literals

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have a number of C# files in the same folder where I used an unclear name for a variable. The problem is that I also used that name appropriately in some string literals, so replace all will also replace those.

I want to do a find and replace all on the files inside a specific folder, finding the word "gelukt" as a variable name and replacing it with the word "status", but not inside of string literals. is this possible without extra tools?

Comment: Use Regular expression for match a string without string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: I'll accept this. in the end, I used the regex 'gelukt(?!("|\.))', because the in-string word was only used at the end of the string.